# Why I have to join tables using find('list')

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.5

There is a strange thing in my project. I have association like this.

```
Novelty->belongsTo->Category
```

And this is model:

```
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');


class Category extends AppModel {

    public $actsAs = array('Tree','Containable');
    public $displayField = 'name';

    public $hasMany = array(
        'Novelty' => array(
            'className' => 'Novelty',
            'foreignKey' => 'category_id',
            'dependent' => false,
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => '',
            'limit' => '',
            'offset' => '',
            'exclusive' => '',
            'finderQuery' => '',
            'counterQuery' => ''
        )
    );
}


class Novelty extends AppModel {

    public $displayField = 'title';

    public $belongsTo = array(
        'Category' => array(
            'className' => 'Category',
            'foreignKey' => 'category_id',
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => ''
        )
    );

}
```

And when I run such command in **Model** file `Novelty.php`, everything runs smooth.

```
$this->find('all',[
    'conditions' => [
        'Category.lft >= ' => $mainCategory['Category']['lft'],
        'Category.rght <= ' => $mainCategory['Category']['rght']
    ],
]);
```

But if I'll change in **Model** file from **all** to **list** I have such Exception:

```
$this->find('list',[
    'conditions' => [
        'Category.lft >= ' => $mainCategory['Category']['lft'],
        'Category.rght <= ' => $mainCategory['Category']['rght']
    ],
]);

Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Category.lft' in 'where clause'
SQL Query: SELECT `Novelty`.`id` FROM `database`.`novelties` AS `Novelty` WHERE `Category`.`lft` >= 110 AND `Category`.`rght` <= 115
```

The same is in the Controller.

Is it some bug, or is it complexity of my project? I use **CakePHP 2.5.1**

Comment: I never used the tree behaviour before and just went through the docu (http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/tree.html) 

I expect your fields lft and rght DO exist?

Does list work, when you don't set a condition?

Comment: You should actually be using JOINs for both - my guess is the first find() you mentioned isn't working as you think either.  It's likely returning ALL Novelties, then also returning the Categories within the left/right conditions.  When you want to limit the results of a main model based on conditions against a related model, you need to use JOINs.

Comment: Also, you don't list what your recursive level is.  It's suggested to set it at -1 in your AppModel, then use Cake's Containable Behavior to get any additional Model's data.